# Is the intersection of a decreasing chain of subsets that span the space still span the space?

Tags: vector-spaces

Suppose, given a vector space $X$, $\{B_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha \in A}$ is a chain of subsets such that $\operatorname {span}(B_{\alpha}) = X$ for any $\alpha \in A$ and $B_{\beta} \supset B_{\gamma}$, for all $\beta < \gamma$.

Is it the case that $\operatorname{span}(\bigcap_{\alpha \in A}{B_{\alpha})} = X$?

**Added**: I was trying to prove "every vector space has a basis" in the opposite way of applying Zorn's lemma to a chain of linearly independent sets. I got stuck when I attempt to find a lower bound for the chain of subsets that span the space.

My second problem is:
Is there some way to characterize properties(of a class of sets)that can be preserved under arbitrary intersection or union?

Comment: This should be clear.

Comment: @user32240：Sorry，I don't get it. Which part should be clear?

Comment: You have $B_{\beta}\supset B_{\gamma}$ for all $\beta<\gamma$. If you assume $\beta<\gamma$ means $\beta\subset \gamma$, then the result you wrote is almost obvious.

Comment: @user32240: One man's hint may become another man's riddle, which is especially applicable to a layman like me. Sorry. I look at your comment, look at it, and look at it, but still can't get it. Could you please elaborate it a little bit or develop it into an answer?

Comment: Just in case of confusion, you can prove that if $A\supset B$, then $span(A)\supset span(B)$. Now pick up a random index $\beta$ and replace all $\alpha$ by $\alpha\cap \beta$, there is no change. We know $\cap_{\alpha}B_{\alpha}$ will only include the indexes which are greater or equal to $\beta$. Therefore by Zorn's lemma there is a maximal element $\beta'$ since every chain has an upper bound given by the intersection of the indexes in the chain. But $\beta'\in A$ and by your assumption $span(B_{\beta'})=X$. So the proof finished this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the vector space $\bf R$, the interval $(-\alpha,\alpha)$ generates $\bf R$ for all $\alpha\ne0$, but the intersection is empty.

Comment: Thank you. That's a simple and neat counterexample!

Comment: Nitpick: If you meant $\alpha>0$, then the intersection isn't empty, just trivial.